# Xamarin Forms: How to select all items from local DB in the sorted order of time

Tags: sqlite, sorting, xamarin.forms

I have implemented local DB in my project and I am using the following code to select all the items from local DB having a particular webContentId.

```
public List<Messages> GetAllItemsByWebContentId(string webContentId)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return database.Table<Messages>().Where(o => o.webContentDefinitionId == webContentId).ToList();
        }
    }
```

`Messages` is my model class.

```
public class Messages
    {
        public Messages()
        {
        }
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int tweetId { get; set; }
        public string profileImage { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public long createdTime { get; set; }
        public string tweetData { get; set; }
        public string mediaUrl { get; set; }
        public string webContentDefinitionId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I need to sort this list in the order of `createdTime`. My `createdTime` is a 13 digit java timestamp.  One example created time is 1543608245696, which means 01/12/2018 01:34. Without sorting, the latest messages are coming on the last of the local database. So inside of `GetAllItemsByWebContentId()` how can I add created time sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy!

change your code to:

```
return database.Table<Messages>()
          .Where(o => o.webContentDefinitionId == webContentId)
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedTime)
          .ToList();
```